# what database should be used for ask and answer site?

Tags: database

I am building an ask and answer site with many categories just like stackexchange. however, I was wondering how to organize database.
Currently, I am organizing as follows:

- **Category** table: stores all categories
- **Question** table: all questions are stored here and cateorized by CategoryID

However, I am afraid that the Question table will grow rapidly and that affect the speed of queries. So, I am wondering ***should I create each Question table for each category***?
For example, I might have:

- **Category** table: stores all categories
- **Technology Question** table: stores questions about technology only
- **Science Question** table: stores questions about Science only
- **Law Question** table: stores questions about Law only

Can anyone give some advice please?
Currently, I am using MySQL DB.

Another concern is that I heard some big Q&A sites use NoSQL DB such as Hadoop, and I dont know whether I should use such big data or not?

Answer (score 0):

It would be harder to organize because if you want to add or remove something from structure you will have to do it for every table and also will have to detect which tables are category tables. Databases can handle large records, you should use one table but design table and queries carefully. If you really keen on this idea, i suggest you to use one table but multiple views instead.